# PyGame rect.move movement not functioning properly

Tags: python, pygame

I am developing my first pygame application in the form of a brick breaker clone. For the player paddle, I am checking for key holds in the main game loop and then redrawing the player object's sprite every frame, as show in the code snippet below:

```
class Player():

def __init__(self):
    self.sprite = pg.transform.scale(pg.image.load('49-Breakout-Tiles.png'), (61,16))
    self.rect = self.sprite.get_rect()
    self.rect.right += displayRect.center[0]-25
    self.rect.top += displayRect.center[1]+450
    self.draw(0)

def draw(self, x):
    pg.draw.rect(display, black, (self.rect.x, self.rect.y, 61, 16))
    self.rect.right += x

    if not displayRect.contains(self.rect):
        self.rect.right -= x

    display.blit(self.sprite, self.rect)


#from gameloop
moveNeg, movePos = False, False

while True:
    for event in pg.event.get():
        if event.type == pg.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pg.K_LEFT or event.key == pg.K_a:
                moveNeg = True
            if event.key == pg.K_RIGHT or event.key == pg.K_d:
                movePos = True
        if event.type == pg.KEYUP:
            if event.key == pg.K_LEFT or event.key == pg.K_a:
                moveNeg = False
            if event.key == pg.K_RIGHT or event.key == pg.K_d:
                movePos = False

    if moveNeg:
        player.draw(-1)
    if movePos:
        player.draw(1)
```

This code works fine, and also ensures that the player paddle stays within the display bounds.

However, for the ball object, I am trying to use `rect.move(x,y)` to move it. I have already tried with `rect.right` and `rect.top` but the ball object is still unresponsive. Here is the code I have so far:

```
class Ball():

def __init__(self):
    self.sprite = pg.transform.scale(pg.image.load('58-Breakout-Tiles.png'), (16, 16))
    self.rect = self.sprite.get_rect()
    self.rect.x += displayRect.center[0]
    self.rect.y += displayRect.center[1]
    self.dir = [random.uniform(-1.0,1.0), random.uniform(-1.0,1.0)]
    print(self.dir)

def draw(self, xy):
    pg.draw.rect(display, black, (self.rect.x, self.rect.y, 16, 16))
    self.rect = self.rect.move(xy[0], xy[1])
    display.blit(self.sprite, self.rect)
```

The ball is centered when the object is initialised (as shown on lines 3/4 of the `__init__` function, but I don't see why this would affect the movement of the ball's `rect`. Also for clarity, `self.dir` is used to give the ball a random starting direction, and I am aware that it is able to move upward with this current configuration.

Since I am new to pygame it completely baffles me as to why my logic is flawed so any help is much appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: Are you sure the `xy` variable being passed to draw is non-zero? Have you tried with updating `rect.x` and `rect.y`?

Comment: @Hoog I have tested it with different variations of numbers between -1 and 1, including 1 and 0.5. I have also tried with updating `rect.x` and `rect.y`, but with no luck.

Comment: It might be worth testing without the if statements:  `if not displayRect.contains(self.rect):....` to make the `draw()` function as simple as possible.  You might be undoing your movement in there.

Comment: @Hoog I tried this, however it made no difference - I would be amazed if it did since the ball is set to be centered in the display, which would have to mean the center was outside of it's own `rect` for the movement to be undone.

Comment: The important thing is it makes the problem smaller, if you took that part out before posting your question no one would waste their time looking there and you would likely get an answer sooner

Comment: I dont see you calling ball draw anywhere

Comment: This question can't be answered with the code you posted. You'll have to show where the `Ball` instance is created, where and how you change `xy` and where you call `Ball.draw`. When posting such a question, you should provide a minimal but runnable example. So take your code and remove anything not related to `Ball`.

Answer (score 4):

[`pygame.Rect.move`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/rect.html#pygame.Rect.move) doesn't change the `Rect` object itself, but it returns an new `Rect` object (Probably the name of the method is misleading).

This means, that

> ```
> self.rect.move(xy[0], xy[1])
> ```

doesn't change anything. You've to assign the rectangle which is returned by `.move` to "itself":

```
self.rect = self.rect.move(xy)
```

---

Alternatively you can use [`pygame.Rect.move_ip()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/rect.html#pygame.Rect.move_ip), moves the rectangle "in place" and changes the `Rect` object:

```py
self.rect.move_ip(xy[0], xy[1])
```

Comment: thank you for saving me from making that mistake, however as I said in my comments to Hoog I have also tried changing the values of `rect.x` and `rect.y` before using `rect.move` and it had no effect. Nevertheless I thank you and I have updated the code to what you suggest..